# Fetching the records by providing optional parameters in Spring

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I need to fetch the records based on the optional parameters.

```
Ex Database: MySql
Tables:
Hotel-> hotel_id, name, group_id, status, brand_id, no_rooms, region_id
Region -> region_id, region_name, region_code, region_manager
```

Region to Hotel having one to many relationship.

I can fetch the hotel records using this type of query

```
Select * from MyDB.Hotel h where h.group_id = 2 and h.brand_id = "ABC" and h.status = "Available" and h.region_id in (select region_id from MyDB.Region r where r.region_code = "13" and r.region_name = "ABC");
```

Similarly I created an api endpoint to get the hotel details by passing group_id, brand_id, status, region_code, region_name as required parameters and able to fetch the records.

I am using Spring CRUD repository.

```
@Query(value="from Hotel h where (h.group =:group) and (h.brand = :brand) and (h.status = :status) and h.region in (from Region r where (r.regionCode =:regionCode) and (r.regionName =:regionName))")
Page<Hotels> findAllHotels (@Param("group") Group group,
                               @Param("brand") Brand brand,
                               @Param("status") String status,
                               @Param("regionCode") EnumProductGroup regionCode,
                               @Param("regionName") EnumProductType regionName,
                               Pageable pageable);
```

Now I need to send the request to same endpoint as optional parameters.

If one parameter is missing still needs to fetch the records based on other parametes. Means the missing parameters should removed from the where conditon dynamically.

I tried to pass the dynamic querystring to the repository query @Query but failed. I don't know is this possible.

request->controller->service->repository extends CrudRepository.

Is there anyway to generate dynamic query based on available parameters or is there any otherway which different than what I am trying.

Comment: You need to write a custom implementation. [Querydsl](http://www.querydsl.com/) and predicates are your friends.

Comment: also this is interresting [query-by-example](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.1.0.M1/reference/html/#query-by-example) - [core.extensions.querydsl](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.1.0.M1/reference/html/#core.extensions.querydsl)

Comment: You can create query in this way also : @Query(value="from Hotel h where (:group is null or h.group =:group) and (:brand is null or h.brand = :brand) and (:status is null or h.status = :status) 
and h.region in (from Region r where (:regionCode is null or r.regionCode =:regionCode) and (:regionName is null or r.regionName =:regionName))")

Comment: @Sanjay Patel: Please correct me if I am wrong. Take the example brand. So I'm receiving brandId as request param if that param doesn't have the value, i am calling repository get method with null object. So, in the clause "and (:brand is null or h.brand = :brand)" if ":brand" is null it will omit from the where clause.

Comment: here if brand id is there then it execute as  (1 is null or h.brand = 1).Here  1 is null become false so it will execute second condition(h.brand=1).           If brand id is null then it will execute first condition and omit second condition.

Comment: I'll try it and see. Also will check on the Patrick idea as well. thx all